# Filter posts according to language WP Globus plugin

Tags: wordpress

I am using WP Globus plugin for my WordPress website. I am using two languages now English and Japanese. When I switch the language to Japanese it shows the Japanese and English posts. I want to filter them means when I switch to Japanese only Japanese posts should be show there and English posts should be skip. Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPGlobus is designed to have the **same** post translated into several languages, not to have posts in English only and other posts - in Japanese only. By default, the post itself does not have any indication of the language it's written in.

There is a premium add-on, called [WPGlobus Plus](https://wpglobus.com/product/wpglobus-plus/). It has many useful functions, and one of them is to mark the language in which the post is written. Technically, it adds post metas with the values "true" or "false" for each language. Visually, in admin, it looks like marking one language as "published" and other(s) as "draft". Then, WPGlobus Plus knows how to filter the loops to show only the "published" languages. Having that, you can see only EN posts when the language is "en" and only JP posts when the language is "jp". And, of course, those posts that have both languages will be shown always.

Hope, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you could try using the [get_locale()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_locale) hook to try and get the current language of the site. I'm not sure though if it will detect the language set by the plugin you're using.

Comment: Locale is already setted by itself or it pass the default language. I want to know how to filter the only one language posts

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand what your trying to do. are you using loops to get the posts? PLS post a snippet of your code for better understanding

Comment: Yes I am using my loops to get code but its showing the Japanese when switch to Japanese and shows English posts when I put the post in only one language English. Means I have not put the Japanese content to it.$args = array('posts_per_page' => $postcount, 'offset' => $offset, 'cat' => $category, 'tag' => $tags, 'orderby' => $order, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => $sticky );
   $widget_loop = new WP_Query($args);

Comment: @RoshanLal show us your loop so we can be more of help

Comment: while ($widget_loop->have_posts()) : $widget_loop->the_post();
     $count = $i++;
     get_template_part('content');
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();

Comment: @tivnet One more query how can I change the WP Globus filter so that only one language posts shown ?